# Setting spinners in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I am trying to set the values for my spinner from a string Array in one of my fragments in the  `onCreateView` in my `public final class Manual extends Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manual, container, false);

    String [] values = 
        {"Time at Residence","Under 6 months","6-12 months","1-2 years","2-4 years","4-8 years","8-15 years","Over 15 years",};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    LTRadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(LTRadapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.manual, container, false);

}
```

I get no errors with my code, however it doesn't set the spinner. The spinner remains blank with no values. Any ideas on why my code isn't setting the spinner?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem was I was returning a new view, not the one I set. I had to `return v;` and it worked fine.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manual, container, false);

    String [] values = 
        {"Time at Residence","Under 6 months","6-12 months","1-2 years","2-4 years","4-8 years","8-15 years","Over 15 years",};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;

}
```

Comment: I literally just made the same mistake as you, thanks for posting this.

Comment: I have took one day to figure out the v.findViewById for the view, thank you very much @Nick